# Can ffmpeg crop jpeg frame

Tags: video, ffmpeg, crop

I know that ffmpeg can crop a video, but I'd like to crop the video and grab frames of the cropped video. The following command runs but doesn't crop the video:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf -crop 1540:1000:250:0 -vf fps-1/1 outimage_%3d.jpeg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do all filtering in one `-vf` or `-filter_complex` instance.

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf "fps=1,crop=1540:1000:250:0" -q:v 2 outimage_%03d.jpeg
```

- I placed fps before crop because it will be faster since your fps value is lower than the input frame rate.
- If you want all frames then remove the fps filter.
- [Control JPEG quality with `-q:v`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10234065/1109017).

Comment: Thanks - that worked perfectly. I was convinced I needed to run a batch convert on the images. This saves so much time.